# Any way to check progress for uninstalling a first-generation managed package?

Tags: managed-package, uninstall, 1gp-package

I kicked off an uninstall of a package and there doesn't seem to be any mechanism I can see to check on how far it has progressed. Considering it's been multiple hours, it'd be great to understand how far along it is in the process.

The installed package page shows the following

1. Expiration Date
2. Uninstall Status
3. Uninstall Date

The status seems to either show "*In Progress*" or "*Uninstall Complete*" once it's done.

There seems to be a `PackageInstallRequest` object in the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_packageinstallrequest.htm) and there's also a [SubscriberPackageVersionUninstallRequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_subscriberpackageversionuninstallrequest.htm) object, but that only applies to second-generation packages.

Since it's a first-generation managed package, I also couldn't use the [force:source:package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm#cli_reference_force_package_uninstall) commands to uninstall and needed to do this through the UI. This leaves me with no `requestId`

I selected to save an export file containing the package data and was hoping I could maybe check progress on that front - but, found no apex/scheduled job that might point to some sort of export of the existing package data.

**Is there any way to check/access more information regarding the progress made on a given uninstall of a first-generation managed package initiated through the UI?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small Update: from [Winter '22](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sfdx_packaging_package_uninstall_enhancements.htm&type=5&release=234), you can see the uninstallation progress in `Setup > Installed Packages`
[image]